# Emacs Lisp - How do you transfer binary files via HTTP?

Tags: http, emacs, couchdb, elisp, file-transfer

Recently, I have been experimenting with using Elisp to communicate with a local CouchDB database via HTTP requests. Sending and receiving JSON works nicely, but I hit a bit of a road-block when I tried to upload an attachment to a document. In the CouchDB tutorial they use this curl command to upload the attachment:

```
curl -vX PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/albums/6e1295ed6c29495e54cc05947f18c8af/artwork.jpg?rev=2-2739352689 \
 --data-binary @artwork.jpg -H "Content-Type:image/jpg"
```

Does anyone know how I would go about using the built-in `url` package to achieve this? I know that it is possible to do upload using multipart MIME requests. There is [a section](http://tkf.github.io/emacs-request/manual.html) in the `emacs-request` manual about it. But I also read that CouchDB does not support `multipart/form-data` as part of their public API, even though Futon uses it under-the-hood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use [`url-retrieve`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/url/Retrieving-URLs.html) and bind `url-request-method` to `"PUT"` around the call.
You will also need to bind `url-request-data` to your data:

```
(let ((url-request-data (with-temp-buffer
                          (insert-file-contents "artwork.jpg")
                          (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) (point-max)))))
  (url-retrieve "http://127.0.0.1:5984/albums/6e1295ed6c29495e54cc05947f18c8af/artwork.jpg?rev=2-2739352689"))
```

Please see also

- [Creating a POST with url elisp package in emacs: utf-8 problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333020/creating-a-post-with-url-elisp-package-in-emacs-utf-8-problem)
- [How does emacs url package handle authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597959/how-does-emacs-url-package-handle-authentication)

You might also find enlightening by reading [the sources](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/url).

Comment: I have tried this; however, I was not sure what to set `url-request-data` to. I tried reading the file as binary and putting it in `url-request-data`; however, this did not work. I think that it is expecting text-encoded data only. Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: Finally managed to test this. Sorry for the late reply! Works a charm thankyou!